# Rails Postgres how to change fix a data column after created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I create a column on a table on postgres. but after created i saw that i made a mistake on accentuation and i would like to instead of destroy the columnn fix it. have a way?

i'm using Rails and console to create the columnn. thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

In your current migration change

```
def change
end
```

to

```
def self.up
  add_column :table_name, column_name, type
end
```

then after this, add

```
def self.down
  remove_column :table_name, column_name
end
```

First run

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION= version_number
```

Now correct the column name in self.up and run

```
run rake db:migrate:up VERSION= version_number
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write migration and rename your column:

```
class RenameColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration 
  def change
    rename_column :table_name, :old_column, :new_column
  end
end
```

and then execute `rake db:migrate` in terminal.

Comment: Yes, execute `rails g migration RenameColumn` to generate file with migration.

Comment: thank's again @Ilya just one thing have a problem if the column is on this way: roupésde-dormir ?

Comment: because i make the migration but is showing block in method_missing

Comment: and i think is because the columnn have this --

Comment: the migration:

    rename_column :categories, :roupasde-dormir, :roupas-de-dormir

Comment: vitrine_production=# TABLE categories;
 id |         slug         |       name        | gender_id |         created_at         |         updated_at         
----+----------------------+-------------------+-----------+----------------------------+----------------------------
 10 | roupas-intimas       | Roupas Íntimas    |         1 | 2016-03-02 13:39:58.600942 | 2016-03-02 13:39:58.600942
 11 | roupas-de-dormir     | Roupas de Dormir  |         1 | 2016-03-02 13:40:57.983162 | 2016-03-02 13:40:57.983162

Comment: you have not column name `:roupasde-dormir`.Maybe you want to rename  field in a table row?

Comment: sorry, i copy the up part here it go:

19 | roupasde-dormir      | Roupasde Dormir   |         2 | 2016-03-02 13:48:27.853552 | 2016-03-02 13:48:27.853552

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it from console.

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.remove_column :table_name, :old_column_name
ActiveRecord::Migration.add_column :table_name, :new_column_name, :type
```

Or use rename_column

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.rename_column :table, :old_column, :new_column
```

But its always better to create migration. You can check llya's answer on how to write migration.